# Вывод названий постов кастомной записи по вхождению в input(автопоиск)?

Tags: wordpress

Пишу ajax пойск.

1. У меня есть то, что пользователь вводит в input

   $searchPostTitle = $_POST['searchField'];
2. Записываю это в аргумент и указываю, с какого типа поста смотреть названия

   $args = [
   'search_title' => $searchPostTitle,
   'post_type' => 'disease',
   ];

Вопрос. Что делать дальше?

Comment: Приведите код, по 4-м строкам описания Вам никто не поможет.

Comment: Хорошо!

Файл main.php

 `<div class="add_review_block">
       <input type="text" class="search_input">
 <div class="result_search"></div>
</div>`

Comment: Файл ajax.js

`jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery) {

    jQuery('.search_input').on('input', function(){
      var textValue = jQuery('.search_input').val();
    
      ajaxSearch(textValue);
    });

function ajaxSearch(textValue){
      jQuery.post(
        myFile.ajaxurl,
         {
         
         action: 'actionSearch',
         searchField: textValue
         },
         function (responce) {
          jQuery('.result_search').html(responce);
            console.log(responce);
         }
       );
    }

`

Comment: Файл function.php

function ajax_search_title(){
 $searchPostTitle = $_POST['searchField'];
 $args = [
  // 'search_title' => $searchPostTitle,
  'post_type' => 'disease',
  ];
 
         add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
  var_dump($query->post_name);
  remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );




 function title_filter( $where, &$wp_query ){
 
   global $wpdb;
                              //  Что писать!?
   return $where;
  }
  }

Comment: Нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1356876/edit) под вопросом, это же невозможно читать.

Comment: Simon, я понимаю.... Вы не подскажите, как можно передать код, что-то типа codepen, только для php + js?

Comment: Да просто добавьте через "пример кода" через обычный редактор на SO.